# Notice (8): Undefined index: id

Tags: php, html, arrays, indexing, echo

I'm trying to get the view to work.  My model is:

```
class LocalClock extends AppModel 
{
    public $useDbConfig = 'default';
    public $useTable = 'local_clocks';
    //public $useTable = false;
public function setStatType( $type )
{
    //$this->table = 'local_clocks';
    $this->_schema = array(
        'col1' => array('type' => 'int')
        ,'col2' => array('type' => 'string')
        ,'col3' => array('type' => 'string')
        ,'col4' => array('type' => 'string')
        ,'col5' => array('type' => 'string')
        ,'col6' => array('type' => 'string')
        ,'col7' => array('type' => 'string')
        ,'col8' => array('type' => 'string')
        ,'col9' => array('type' => 'string')
        ,'col10' => array('type' => 'string')
        ,'col11' => array('type' => 'string')
        ,'col12' => array('type' => 'string')
        ,'col13' => array('type' => 'string')
        ,'col14' => array('type' => 'string')
    );   
}
```

}

The controller is this:

```
class LocalClocksController extends AppController 
{
    public $scaffold = 'admin';     // allow basic view/edit for administrators
    public $components = array('RequestHandler');   // enable checking for incoming request attributes

   public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
public function index() 
{
if ($this->RequestHandler->accepts('xml'))
{
    $this->LocalClock->table = 'local_clocks';
    $this->LocalClock->getDataSource()->tableFields['local_clocks'] = array( "id", "name", "auto_offset", "utc_offset_sec", "in_month", "in_week", "in_day", "in_hour", "out_month", "out_week", "out_day", "out_hour", "offset_sec");
        // xml handler
    $this->set('localClocks', $this->LocalClock->find('all'));
    $this->set('_serialize', array('local_clocks'));
    }
    elseif ($this->RequestHandler->accepts('json'))
    {
    $this->LocalClock->getDataSource()->tableFields['local_clocks'] = array( "id", "name", "auto_offset", "utc_offset_sec", "in_month", "in_week", "in_day", "in_hour", "out_month", "out_week", "out_day", "out_hour", "offset_sec");
        $this->set('localClocks', $this->LocalClock->find('all'));
        $this->set('_serialize', array('local_clocks'));
    }
elseif( $this->RequestHandler->accepts('html'))
{
    $this->LocalClock->table = 'local_clocks';
    $this->LocalClock->getDataSource()->tableFields['local_clocks'] = array( "id", "name", "auto_offset", "utc_offset_sec", "in_month", "in_week", "in_day", "in_hour", "out_month", "out_week", "out_day", "out_hour", "offset_sec");
        $this->set('localClocks', $this->LocalClock->find('all'));
}       
}
```

}

And this is the view:

```
<p><marquee><u>Local Clocks</u></marquee></p>

<table>
<thead><tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Auto Offset</th>
<th>UTC Offset Sec</th>
<th>In Month</th>
<th>In Week</th>
<th>In Day</th>
<th>In Hour</th>
<th>Out Month</th>
<th>Out Week</th>
<th>Out Day</th>
<th>Out Hour</th>
<th>Offset Sec</th>
<th>Actions</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>

<?php 
foreach($localClocks as $LocalClock) { ?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $LocalClock['id']; ?></td>

<td><input type="button" value="View"/><input type="button" value="Edit"/><input type="button" value="Delete"/></td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>

</tbody>
</table>
<?php debug($LocalClock); ?>
```

I am getting the "Notice (8): Undefined index: id [APP/View/LocalClocks/index.ctp, line 37]" error

This is the output of debug($LocalClock) (the LocalClock from the foreach loop in the view file

```
array(
    'LocalClock' => array(
        'id' => '4',
        'name' => 'New Test Clock',
        'auto_offset' => false,
        'utc_offset_sec' => '9',
        'in_month' => '8',
        'in_week' => '7',
        'in_day' => '6',
        'in_hour' => '5',
        'out_month' => '4',
        'out_week' => '3',
        'out_day' => '2',
        'out_hour' => '1',
        'offset_sec' => '0'
    )
)
```

Any help with how to correctly display the id would be great.
I am also trying to display the other properties like the auto-offset, utc_offset_sec, in_month etc but i left those out of the view file for simplicity.

Also, in the model file at the top, do I really need the function setStateType($type) ?
And if i do need the function, what about the $this->_schema = array() code, do I need that as well.

I am using cakephp, and I am new to this.  ALso, the code I have is from a different section of the same big project I am working on.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$LocalClock['LocalClock']['id'];
```

IIRC, cakephp puts the Model name as the first element in the array so you need to access `LocalClock` first.

Your debug shows this:

```
array(
    'LocalClock' => array(
//This One ^
        'id' => '4',
        'name' => 'New Test Clock',
        'auto_offset' => false,
        'utc_offset_sec' => '9',
        'in_month' => '8',
        'in_week' => '7',
        'in_day' => '6',
        'in_hour' => '5',
        'out_month' => '4',
        'out_week' => '3',
        'out_day' => '2',
        'out_hour' => '1',
        'offset_sec' => '0'
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your view to:

```
<p><marquee><u>Local Clocks</u></marquee></p>

<table>
<thead><tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Auto Offset</th>
<th>UTC Offset Sec</th>
<th>In Month</th>
<th>In Week</th>
<th>In Day</th>
<th>In Hour</th>
<th>Out Month</th>
<th>Out Week</th>
<th>Out Day</th>
<th>Out Hour</th>
<th>Offset Sec</th>
<th>Actions</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>

<?php 
foreach($localClocks as $LocalClock) { 
extract($LocalClock);
?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $LocalClock['id']; ?></td>

    <td><input type="button" value="View"/><input type="button" value="Edit"/><input type="button" value="Delete"/></td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>

</tbody>
</table>
<?php debug($LocalClock); ?>
```

This method uses an extract, which assigned variables from array key/values. This is not the most ideal, but will work.